# How can you re-synchronize oracle streams automatically?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-streams

I have noticed that when a process of oracle streams (e.g. capture/apply/propagate) is stopped or disabled, and at the same time, changes are made to the source and/or destination table/database/schema, the changes are not automatically re-synchronized when the streams processed are re-enabled.

You would then need to manually recreate the capture/apply/propagate processes in order for the data to be replicated again. Is there an automated way to do this without manually checking which tables are out of sync and manually recreating each process for each table? Please take note of the following conditions:

- Replication is on a per table basis setup and there are alot of tables involved, but not to the extent that schema replication is recommended.
- Oracle version used is 11gR2